# Can a cast iron sewer pipe union be above roof line?

Tags: plumbing, roof, vent, sewer, cast-iron

Should this sewer pipe connection be below the roof line? Is there a code stating this should be below the roofline?

[image]

Comment: In New Jersey - we had to make custom pipe collar due to Union being too wide for standard - haven’t seen and unions above roof line on being le roofs

Comment: Put all information in your question, please, and not down here. Take the [tour].